# how to clean page cache in linux programmatically

Tags: c++, c

I need to clean page cache in Linux Ubuntu. There is a command to clean page cache echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches which can be done through terminal but I need to clean page cache programmatically. Will understanding this souce code of drop_caches.c i.e http://www2.comp.ufscar.br/lxr/source/fs/drop_caches.c help me in solving my problem.

Comment: Please post the code here in a [MCVE]

Comment: The duplicate is gone (deleted). Since this is now a dupe *target* then perhaps this should be opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably stuck with opening the file `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, writing 1 to it and close it again. There is no dedicated syscall for that operation.

```
sync();
int fd = open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", O_WRONLY);
write(fd, "1", 1);
close(fd);
```

Depending on what you try to achieve, the (optional) preceding `sync()` can help free some more memory.

Comment: Thanks @Ctx is there any other way to clean page cache?

Comment: @TalhaA I am quite confident that the sysctl-interface is the only way to clean the page cache explicitely. Write "3" to it to also clean directory entry and inode cache.

Comment: basically I have to do a small project for **cache clean** in Linux and I know basic level Linux programming, like fork/exec,sys calls,modules and threading.So what more can I do in this to clean cache?

Comment: @TalhaA The code snippet I provided does exactly that, why not just use that?

Comment: can I create a system call to clean cache/page cache ?

Comment: @TalhaA Yes, this is possible, but where do you see the advantage? You would have to patch the kernel (since there is no clean way for adding a new syscall with a kernel module) and do that again with every kernel upgrade.